# can't access AWS DynamoDB from a local Java application (outside of the cloud)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I wanted to access DynamoDB (real, not local) from my Java application running on my local machine.
I set the environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE.

Despite of this, I'm getting the error:

"com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The security token included in the request is invalid (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException"

Here is the code (it's Kotlin):

```
val client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
        .build()
val dynamoDB = DynamoDB(client)
val table = dynamoDB.getTable("SomeTable")
val key = "some-key-field"
val spec = GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("some-key-value", key)
val result = table.getItem(spec).toJSONPretty().toString()
println(result)
dynamoDB.shutdown()
```

Is it possible to access AWS DynamoDB from a local Java (JVM) application like this? What is missing here?

P.S.:

I can access DynamoDB from AWS CLI, it's working, the problem is with access from my application.

**Update:**

Found how to set the credentials but it didn't help.

```
val accessKey = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
val accessSec = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
val client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSec)))
        .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
        .build()
```

The error is the same.

Comment: Hi,
I'm not a Java guy, but in javascript you have to add the credentials in the constructor.
For example (in JS):
`const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({accessKeyId: 'xxx', secretAccessKey: 'xxx'});`
I think you have to do something similar in your code.

Comment: I'd re-verify your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.  The other two are not used.  They should match what is in your .aws/credentials file for the profile you're using.

Comment: @eL_Finito Yes, I've found how to set the credentials. I thought that the environment variables are picked up automatically but they are probably not. I added the credentials, however, even this didn't help me.

Comment: @stdunbar Verified. Unfortunately, I haven't seen any mismatch.